# delete row i uitableview working but cant reflect always on iphone

Tags: iphone

i can successfuly delete data from tableview , but when i go to main menu and come back then i see all the old data,

how to make data consistent , i.e   once deleted it will be gone forever

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = (DatabaseTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        {
     appDelegate.favDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2",@"4",nil];
        }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    appDelegate = (DatabaseTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];



     NSString *cc=[appDelegate.favDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@" vale is %d",indexPath.row);
    // Configure the cell...
     NSArray *theParameters = [cc componentsSeparatedByString:@","];



    NSLog(@"array is %@",cc);
          NSLog(@"arraytheParameters is %@",theParameters);

    cell.text=cc;//theParameters;
    return cell;
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   NSLog(@"matrix is her%@",appDelegate.favDetail);
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source



        [appDelegate.favDetail removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }   

     /*
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    } */


}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ [tableView reloadData];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; // no use , it shows old data
}
```

thanks

Comment: Put a break point in viewDidLoad and check whether it is getting called when you are coming back for the second time. I think you are reloading the array with the old value again

Comment: yes its old data , how to load new data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to save the state of your model beyond the life of your table view controller, there are few things you can do. One is to write the array to a file in the documents directory and read it back on reload. This would work well will small sets of data. But if you are going to use a large data set, you have to use [`Core Data`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

As for this specific case, you are reinitializing the data on every `viewDidLoad`. I suggest you do this in `viewDidLoad` –

```
...
if ( appDelegate.favDetail == nil ) {
    appDelegate.favDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2",@"4",nil];
}
...
```

This will make sure that you don't reinitialize it.

Comment: just 1 more question , in nav bar i have back button and edit button , now  where to put "ADD" button so that user can add data also ??

Comment: Well, you can add an extra button in the end which is titled `Add` or you could consider adding a toolbar to the setup. However adding it only for the sake of a single button might not be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

you have to delete the data in both your view and your model

Comment: can you explain what exactly you mean??

Answer (score 0):

Check out the place where appDelegate.favDetail is getting data from...

While deleting you are removing from appDelegate.favDetail but When you go to main menu and come back you are reassigning the values to appDelegate.favDetail...

Checkout that appDelegate.favDetail only gets the value once.. or another option is you remove the data from the main source from where the favDetail gets the value

Happy iCoding....

Comment: u r alwayz welcome prajakta... but getting a vote is the best way to thanks :P